# Hey how can I adjust the thickness of the survival curve in ggsurvplot?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

The simple size parameter does not work. Do you have any other options? I would like to make the curve smaller.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Using the example from the help page, `ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, size = 0.5)` works for me with R 3.6.1 and survminer 0.4.7. Which package and R versions are you using?

Comment: I have R version 4.00 and survminer 0.4.3